# Issues with IP Address and Domain Restrictions in IIS 10

Tags: iis

I Have a IIS 10 running into a MS Windows 2016 Standard.

I install IP Address and Domain Restrictions for manage which ip adress is allowed to access to application

but i can't make which Ip is allowed and which IP is deny to access

I try to make IP range but it is refused by Windows

Comment: "but i can't make which Ip is allowed and which IP is deny to access" What do you mean by "make"? That's an unusual term here.

Comment: Sorry Sir ! i mean : for example only the @IP 192.168.1.5 is allowed to visit the web application , the author is not allowed

Comment: Could you please tell me how your make the IP range in the IIS? What you mean about refused by windows? Does it show any error message? If you don't know how to set it, you could refer to this [article]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc730889(v=ws.10)

Comment: @BrandoZhang in add allow restrection Rule , when i add in " Ip address range"  like that : 192.168.1.3-192.168.1.6 , Windows send "192.168.1.3-192.168.1.6 " is an invalid Ip address"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i add in " Ip address range" like that : 192.168.1.3-192.168.1.6 , Windows send "192.168.1.3-192.168.1.6 " is an invalid Ip address"

As far as I know, we couldn't add the range like "192.168.1.3-192.168.1.6" in IIS range.We should use sub mask.

Example:

Ban the lower half: 192.168.1.1 - "192.168.1.127

IP Address Range: 192.168.1.0
Mask or Prefix: 255.255.255.128

The mask 255.255.255.128 is also known as a "/25", because 25 of the first 32 bits of the address are part of the network address, and the remaining 7 bits are used for host addresses.

[image]

I suggest you could refer to below article to understand how sub mask work with IP address.

Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnetting

If you want to check your sub mask is right or not, use an online calculator. This one is fairly decent:
https://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators.php

Comment: Thank you , i will try and tell you the result